# Excel issue with conditional formatting and rules

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

**The database in question:**

[image]

I am trying to create an excel database to use at work. I am having trouble with a few formulas. The dates in columns L,M,N and O are dependant on the date value entered in column H. I need each column to change colour when the date in the cell is less than or equal to todays date. This part I have managed to do. But the first issue I am having is when the next date is reached I would like the previous cell date to return to normal, So only one colour is displayed at a time. I am also having trouble getting the cells in column P to remain white/blank when cell value is blank

Comment: What conditional formatting rules have you tried?

Comment: So for my 10 day, 15 day 21 day due date I have a formula in the cells which are =(h2)+9 for the 10 day +14 for the 15 day and so on.

Comment: Why did you put a cfr on column P? Why haven't you included the cfrr rules you are using now?

Comment: the conditional formatting rule I used was =$L$2<=TODAY() which turns yellow when the date is reached

Answer (score 1):

For column L it looks like you created a CFR based upon a formula like,

```
=and($l2<today(), $p2="")
```

Add another condition to the formula.

```
=and($l2<today(), $m2>=today()), $p2="")
```

For column M this becomes,

```
=and($m2<today(), $n2>=today()), $p2="")
```

... and so on.